# Sql Server Compact Edition 4.0 performance for asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, performance, sql-server-ce

I'm considering migrating to SQL CE 4.0 for my website projects, all of my sites use Umbraco but they aren't seriously busy websites (up to 15,000 visits month).

My main concern is performance, so I was wondering if anyone had any experience or knowledge on what sort of performance limitations I can expect.

Also, if running in a managed host environment do I need to be concerned about application pool memory limits?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the website should be no problem, because it reads all from cache.
But I'm having trouble with the CMS performance, on my local environment but also on my VPS and on a shared hosting environment. It takes a lot of waiting time before items are created and edited. That's a big issue for my customer right now.
I do run the latest version of Umbraco (4.7.2.1) which should include a lot of performance improvements for SQL CE. 
It might get even worse when the datbase size is growing (mine is about 92Mb)